# Double lock with volatile or memory barrier

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, volatile, memory-barriers

This is the code I have in place, running for couple of months with no issues.

```
public sealed class Singleton 
{
    private static Singleton value;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    public static Singleton Value 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Singleton.value == null) 
            {
                lock (syncRoot) 
                {
                    if (Singleton.value == null) 
                    {
                        Singleton.value = new Singleton();
                    }
                }
            }
            return Singleton.value;
        }
    }      
}
```

However, I came across this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/05/13/volatile-and-memorybarrier/) and it outlined issues with the above.

a) Write `Singleton.value = new Singleton();` may get cached on the processor so the other thread may not end up seeing it. To fix this `volatile` keyword is used.

**Q(1)**: Doesn't the C# `lock` keyword take care of this ?

b) Another better solution outlined, in the same article, then is to avoid `volatile` and introduce `System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();` after the write to `Singleton.value`.

**Question**:

**Q(2)** I don't quite understand the need for `MemoryBarrier()` after the write. What possible re-ordering could potentially cause the other thread to see `Singleton.value` as null ? The `lock` prevents other threads from even reading anything.

**Q(3)** Barriers will just maintain order but what if the value is still read from some cache instead. Isn't volatile still required ?

**Q(4)** Is barrier really required there since C# `lock` itself places it ?

Finally,
Do I need to update my code with either approach or is it good enough ?

**Edits**
There is an answer proposed to use `Lazy` initialization. I got it.

But what were they trying to accomplish using volatie and memorybarrier that lock doesn't guarantee ?

Comment: See also [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Comment: I'm not even sure what you are trying to ask.  Are you just trying to implement a singleton?

Comment: Some Microsoft employees will never completely recover from having to deal with the Itanium processor.  Unfortunately the nonsense they pulled with volatile to tame the beast made it in the C# spec as well.  All irrelevant today.  Use the Lazy class.

Comment: Ok but can anyone explain what they were trying to accomplish with memorybarrier and volatile back in those days ?

Comment: @FrankQ. "The processor executing the current thread cannot reorder instructions in such a way that memory accesses prior to the call to MemoryBarrier execute after memory accesses that follow the call to MemoryBarrier." So without the MemoryBarrier Itanium processors will reorder the instructions.

Comment: The linked MSDN article is fundamentally flawed. A solitary memory barrier is useless – you need another barrier with the read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This is the code I have in place, running for couple of months with no issues.

If there's a one-in-a-billion chance of failure, and the code runs a thousand times a day on a thousand machines, that's a on average one impossible-to-debug critical failure every three years.

If it only fails on particular hardware, and you do all your testing on x86, then you'll never see the failure.

There is no such thing as testing for correctness of low-lock code. The code is either provably correct, or it's not. You can't rely on testing.

> Doesn't the C# lock keyword take care of this?

The lock is elided on one of the reads.

> The lock prevents other threads from even reading anything.

The lock is elided on one of the reads.

> Barriers will just maintain order but what if the value is still read from some cache instead. Isn't volatile still required ?

Reading from a cache is equivalent to moving a read backwards in time; barriers induced by volatile or explicit barriers impose restrictions on how such backwards movements can be observed.

> Is barrier really required there since C# lock itself places it ?

The lock is elided on one of the reads.

> Do I need to update my code with either approach or is it good enough?

I would never, ever write code like this.  If you need lazy initialization, use `Lazy<T>`. If you need a singleton, use the standard implementation of the singleton pattern.  Don't solve these problems yourself; let experts solve these problems for you.

> But what were they trying to accomplish using volatile and memorybarrier that lock doesn't guarantee ?

They were trying to correctly elide a lock, thereby saving a few nanoseconds in the non-contended path. How valuable are those nanoseconds to your user, compared with the costs of hard-to-debug rare critical failures?

Any time you try to elide a lock you are *fully immersed in the crazy world of the low-level memory model*.  You have to assume that all memory is constantly changing unless something is keeping it still; you have to assume that any and all legal re-orderings of memory accesses are possible, *even ones that are impossible on most hardware*. You don't know what weird hardware is going to be invented in the future and used to run your code.

Don't go there. I don't like to use threads; if I want to parallelize something my preference is to throw virtual machines, containers, or processes at the problem. If you have to use threads, try to not share memory. If you have to share memory, use the highest level constructs built by experts, like `Task` and `Lazy`, rather than rolling your own out of memory barriers and interlocked operations.

Comment: "I don't like to use threads" - priceless! Most problems are not solved this way. If your problem cant be solved on 1 'thread', `x` 'threads' is not going to improve it by any factor.

Comment: _"Don't solve these problems yourself; let experts solve these problems for you."_ –  Then, you'll never become an expert.  I prefer: given time, try to solve these problems to understand what experts deal with; without time, at least reason about the problem and choose safety first.

Comment: @acelent: The problem with that usually-sensible approach is that chip manufacturers have given us a world where *nothing works sensibly in multithreaded programs*. I have given the memory model of C# a *lot* of thought in the last ten years and concluded that *I do not understand it well enough to write non-trivial solutions with confidence that they are correct*. I try to avoid sharing memory across threads whenever possible; if I cannot then I follow an established correct pattern *exactly* rather than trying to reason about the crazy world of the memory model.

Comment: Ok, imagine someone at [math.se] with a reputation like you saying *"Don't solve these problems yourself; let experts solve these problems for you."* or *"Don't go there. I don't like <subject>;"* on any math subject at all.  [so] is definitely the site for these subjects, unlike, say, [softwareengineering.se] (or [physics.se]), where this advice would probably be more on spot. Other than this, I agree with what you've posted and commented on this question.

Comment: @acelent: If someone on Mathematics said "your 'proof' of P=NP does not even begin to address the two-dozen problems in such proofs known to experts for decades; don't go there, it's a waste of your time and the time of everyone you'll bother with your crank proofs", then I would treat that as a public service.  I'm giving solid, practical engineering advice here. **We have failed as language designers**. We've built systems that are too complicated to use correctly, and failed to advocate for simpler, safer systems.  I'm trying to mitigate that in what small ways I can.

Comment: I would agree with you if the question would lack effort and research.  But, it's a matter of opinion, so I'll stop here.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by just using Lazy to generate your instance for you:

```
public sealed class Singleton 
{
    private static Lazy<Singleton> _value = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Value => _value.Value;
}
```

As people much smarter than me have pointed out, most of the time this can be even more simplified through the use of a static initializer:

```
public sealed class Singleton 
{
    public static Singleton Value = new Singleton();
}
```

Refer to Eric Lippert's comments on my answer for the key difference between these approaches and what might help you make the decision between one or the other.

Comment: There's no reason at all to even use a `Lazy`, just initialize the static field directly as it's *already* safe.  The entire solution needs nothing more than `public static Singleton Value {get;} = new Singleton();`

Comment: @Servy: Though I thoroughly agree with you -- that's the right thing to do 99.999% of the time -- there is a difference. The static field initializer runs when the *class* is accessed for the first time; the lazy operation runs when the *property* is accessed for the first time. If there's a scenario where the operation is insanely expensive *and* the class might be accessed long before the property is accessed, then it *could* be worthwhile to use a lazy initializer.

Comment: @EricLippert And so, in cases where a singleton class has operations that *don't* involve accessing the singleton instance, using a `Lazy` is a useful feature (it's not, really, as the *true* solution in that case is to move that logic out of the class as it apparently is separate from the singleton).  Using `Lazy` everywhere, even when you will never need it, is not productive.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the use of a simple static initializer